# Getting error while trying to add header with Set-Cookie in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I am trying to include external python module in my project for working with sessions. It's named `gmemsess.py`. It tries to add Set-Cookie header in the response and an error appears:

```
rh.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie','%s=%s; path=/;'%(name,self._sid))
AttributeError: HeaderDict instance has no attribute 'add_header'
```

I read documentation and everything seems ok, but it doesn't work. Why this error can appear?
Also, I use webapp2 to manage subdomains. May be there is something goes wrong because of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `headers.add_header` method should absolutely work if you are using stock AppEngine, but I am guessing that you are using a framework -- and there are plenty of them, like Bottle -- that uses a custom replacement for [webob's Response](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/#response) object.

A little bit of time with Google reveals that there is at least one identifiable class called HeaderDict that extends MultiDict, and I think that is what you are dealing with. In that case, you should to into `gmemsess.py` and change the line

```
rh.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie','%s=%s; path=/;'%(name,self._sid))
```

to read

```
rh.response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = '%s=%s; path=/;'%(name,self._sid)
```

That should fix you right up.

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right, already did this, and it works fine, thanks!

Comment: After this question appeared, I included add_header (and a couple of other wsgiref.headers.Headers methods) to webapp2.Response. The related issue was described here: http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=6

Answer (score 3):

**Disregard -- see comments below**

Is that module written to work with App Engine? The response objects used by App Engine do not have an `add_header` method, see [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass.html).

Instead, there's a dict-like object `headers` that you can just assign values to like

```
response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = "whatever your cookie value is"
```

Comment: Hm, author says he created that module specially for GAE. Here is the module's project page: http://code.google.com/p/gmemsess/.

Comment: Duh -- I didn't follow the chain all the way, http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.headers says that there should be an `add_header` method, but your traceback says that you're working with a `HeaderDict` object, not a wsgiref `headers` object. Disregard my answer.

Comment: How are you creating the session object? Can you post the `get()` request handler that you're using?

Comment: I tried to update strings containing add_header method so that they were with dicts instead. There were 2 such strings. It seems to be working fine now. But I am not sure I did it right way as author wanted it to be.

Comment: You should just be able to pass in `self` to the `Session()` constructor from within your `get()` handler  and things should work correctly.

Comment: I suppose it works different way because I use webapp2 and an extension to it named routes.py to manage subdomains and routing. So, I run WSGIApplication not with wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application), but with special webapp2 method application.run(). What do you think?